# scapy sniff() function fails while running scapy in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, scapy

I'm just starting to learn about packets, and I have started using scapy to learn about them.

I installed scapy, and I'm getting the menu running correctly. However, when I try using the sniff() function like so (in the cmd):

```
 packets = sniff(count = 2)
```

it seems like scapy is stuck in infinite `while True` look without breaking out of it. Visually the cmd is just stuck and I cannot do anything to get out of scapy.

I searched online but couldn't find any solution to that.

**This is what the cmd looks like, while running cmd as administrator**

[image: out put]

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
After playing with scapy on a different pc for a bit, I think the problem might occur because for some reason, `sniff()` function does not receive any packets, or doesn't have permissions to receive them, so it cannot finish successfully. Any ideas why is this happening, and what can I do to solve this?

Comment: And are you sending/receiving packets on the interface scapy is sniffing on?  Have you tried sending pings meanwhile?  If scapy has been launched with administrator rights, then permissions should not be a problem.  Otherwise `sniff` would have raised an exception. Other thing to try: use the `iface` parameter of `sniff` to explicitly specify the interface you're listening on.

Comment: Hey,  thanks for your answer!
This seems to solve the problem, however, is there a way to implicitly set the active interface? It's quite hard to maintain such a long parameter every time I want to perform a simple sniff. @qouify